# How to insert Horizontal cut in delta symbol?

Tags: beamer, symbols

How do we write the Greek delta symbol with a cut in it as in `\hbar` (which produces a cut in h)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 10):

Probably you are meaning `\dh` (U+00F0 LATIN SMALL LETTER ETH)?
This is available in encoding `T1`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame} 
    \dh
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: I don't know whether to upvote this!

Answer (score 10):

I copied the definition of `\hbar`, but inserted `\delta` instead of `h` and adjusted kerning.

```
\nopagenumbers% for cropping
\def\deltabar{{\mathchar '26\mkern -10mu\delta}}
$\delta$
$\hbar$
$\deltabar$
\bye
```

[image]